# Should I give attribution for transitive dev-dependencies?

Tags: licensing, attribution

I'm working on a library/cli-tool for bundling dependency licenses into a single file.
Currently, I'm trying to collect licenses of: direct dependencies, transitive-dependencies and **direct *dev*-dependencies**.

In other words, I'm trying to collect licenses of packages, that are installed in node_modules.
Transitive dev-dependencies are not installed by the package manager, because of the very nature of dev-dependencies.

I'm worried, whether or not code portions of those transitive dependencies somehow can be included in installed packages.

For example: Project "A" depends on Package "B". Package "B" has Transpiler "C" as a dev-dependency. Code generated by Transpiler "C" in Package "B" includes not only simple transpilation result, but also some polyfill for a function, that is not available in older browsers, from Transpiler "C".
But, because Transpiler "C" is a transitive dev-dependency, it is not installed in node_modules of Project "A", so without manually installing it, Transpiler "C"-s license cannot be properly obtained, can it? Even if we could, we will have to look for Transpiler "C"-s dependencies/dev-dependencies too, etc, etc.

In this hypothetic case, we have only one transitive dev-dependency, but, in real-world scenarios, there could be hundreds. There could be several versions of the same package defined as a transitive dev-dependency in different packages. By manually installing transitive dev-dependencies for collecting license information, these transitive dev-dependencies could have their own dev dependencies, which will be needed to be installed too. This process will have to be repeated until all transitive dev-dependencies of all transitive dev-dependencies are installed.

Question is: Should I care for collecting license information about transitive dev-dependencies?
And if I should, to which point?

I already care for regular transitive-dependencies, but I'm worried for transitive dev-dependencies.

Comment: The [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project is related to your concerns. See also [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (and [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org)...). Send me an email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` for more information

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, this could be a PhD work. See e.g. [Stefano Zacchiroli publications](https://upsilon.cc/~zack/)

Comment: See also http://softwareheritage.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a really tricky scenario, which is why automated license compliance tools can only go so far. Your analysis seems generally correct.

In practice, I would expect that the license of B doesn't just cover B's original source code, but also B's transpiled code (at least if B is distributed in transpiled form). This would neatly sidestep the issue of transitive dev dependencies. However, this points to a more general problem: license metadata might not be accurate, another reason why automated tools only go so far.

If you are designing a general-purpose tool, it might be useful to add an *option* that also triggers analysis of dev dependencies and transitive dev dependencies, by fetching metadata for tools mentioned in the package metadata (no need to actually install them). By default, I would not expect dev dependencies to have any direct effect on the licensing status (although, as you correctly explain, especially polyfills could violate this expectation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!